# Issue displaying $('a') is not a function on console

Tags: jquery

I want to append some parameters from current link to all hrefs in the current page.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var this_url = document.URL;
    var param_segment = new Array();
    param_segment = this_url.split("?");
    var param_fragment = param_segment[1];
    var param_sub_fragments = new Array();
    var param_sub_fragments = param_fragment.split("&");
    var actual_param = "?" + param_sub_fragments[0] + "&" + param_sub_fragments[1] + "&" + param_sub_fragments[2];

    $('a').each(function()
    {
        this.href += actual_param;
    })
});
```

I am getting some errors on console regarding this piece of section:

```
$('a').each(function()
    {
        this.href += actual_param;
    })
```

The error console is this:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function


$('a').each(function()
```

What error am I doing??

Comment: Do you have Jquery included in your page?

Comment: you mean jquery library??

Comment: Yeah It seems like you don't have it included but that should also make an error at $(document), could you put your code in a fiddle?

Comment: yes you most probably are missing jquery.js library

Comment: either the jquery lib is missing, or maybe you are calling your code before it's included

Comment: no, the library is added and its included before the code... if i amputting an alert before the $('a') then i can have the alert displayed..... if its that library missiing issue, then it wont enter into the $(document) on first hand

Comment: you should upload the Jquery file if you are using Jquery code, make sure you include your Jquery file before your Js file and also  be sure that you are not including the Jquery file multiple times

Comment: http://android-system-alert.mobile-virus-scan.com/techsupport/paypercall/index.php?p1=gomotrak&p2=com&p3=main&number=+877-774-5513&c=1144&subid=1942685229-f762d965d34a7727171b81e9f534cdb2&l=15777&ept=4BKfkxTzLZ3jF1b76H44TcVSXRyzUbiTWhHsuCx2TokIQ8SXLC2lJ%2BJiaILY17mSvpSJpRMfk%2FLBfy4Wtjsbfg%3D%3D

Comment: you can check the link i am giving...............             http://android-system-alert.mobile-virus-scan.com/techsupport/paypercall/index.php?p1=gomotrak&p2=com&p3=main&number=+877-774-5513&c=1144&subid=1942685229-f762d965d34a7727171b81e9f534cdb2&l=15777&ept=4BKfkxTzLZ3jF1b76H44TcVSXRyzUbiTWhHsuCx2TokIQ8SXLC2lJ%2BJiaILY17mSvpSJpRMfk%2FLBfy4Wtjsbfg%3D%3D

Comment: your link is leading to this link http://www.bing.com/search?q=1422524381

Comment: So to what is refferring `$`? You have to debug it on your side. Anyway, you have to provide sample replicating issue in question itself

Comment: check this link then                 http://gomotrak.com/main/click.php?c=1144&key=i0yqrqc842o38sc5d263mpo2

Comment: @A.Wolff, sample replicating means??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find nothing wrong with your code when run in a JSFiddle, so, in case `$` has been globally overridden, try this alternate DOM ready (explicit jQuery with local `$`):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
     // Your code here
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/bx5g7d2o/2/

This is the shortcut equivalent of:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Your code here
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This should fix his error, I think he has several confilicting libs.

Comment: it was due to the jquery.conflict()... blcking that resolved the problem... however if i want to keep that, then what shall i do??

Comment: As the problem was not with the code shown, please show the rest of your code/page :)